# How to get multer image in backend(nest) file to on my frontend(react)?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, multer

I have a question while making the avatar image(url) in user sign up form on my project.

frontend: react.js
backend: nest.js

First of all, I saved my avatar image in server folder with using multer. and then i want to get avatar image to my frontend but i have no idea about next step.

code is below..

**main.ts**

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  });

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    }),
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    }),
  );

  app.use('/avatar', express.static(join(__dirname, '../avatar')));

  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**sign up code (Controller)**

```
@Post('signup')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('avatar', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: Helper.destinationPath,
        filename: Helper.customFileName,
      }),
    }),
  )
  async postSignUpData(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body()
    body: UserSignDataDto,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {
    //
    if (file !== null) {
      body.avatar = file;
    }
    //
    try {
      const result = await this.userService.signUpUserData(body);

      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Create new Account!',
        data: result,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: error.message,
      });
    }
  }
```

**sign up service logic**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('UserData') private userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
  ) {}
  //
  async signUpUserData(signUpData: UserSignDataDto) {
    //
    const { userId, pass1, pass2, email, nickname, avatar } = signUpData;

    const checkExists: boolean = await this.userModel.exists({
      $or: [{ userId }, { email }, { nickname }],
    });

    if (checkExists) {
      throw new Error(`This user id or email or nickname is already taken.`);
    }

    if (pass1 !== pass2) {
      throw new Error(`Password does not match`);
    }

    const user = new this.userModel({
      userId,
      password: pass2,
      email,
      nickname,
      avatarUrl: avatar ? avatar.path : 'Not Avatar',
    });

    return await user.save();
  }
```

How can I front load the saved avatar image from avatar folder..

Please let me know if you have a suitable example.

Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

Your server should be configured to serve static files (images and other) and the URL saved in `user.avatarUrl` should point to one of the images.